# AWS API Gateway Routing to Root Resource with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

**Architecture**

My setup is as such

API GW (REST API) -> VPC LINK -> NLB -> Listener/Target -> ECS Service -> EC2 Container Instances.

My container instances are up and running.
My service is up and running.
My NLB has registered the container instances as targets.

All health checks are passing.

My integration looks like

```
vpc_integration = apigateway.Integration(
            type=apigateway.IntegrationType.HTTP_PROXY,
            integration_http_method=HttpMethods.ANY,
            options=apigateway.IntegrationOptions(
                connection_type=apigateway.ConnectionType.VPC_LINK, vpc_link=link
            ),
        )
```

I have an API GW resource `/my_method/{param}`

I am able to directly invoke my api through the NLB eg. `curl -X GET http://mynlb.../my_method/param`

When invoking directly with curl. I get a proper response and can also see my expected container log output.

This was all deployed with CDK.

**Problem**
When I test from within the API Gateway Console. I receive a 404

```
Sun Jul 30 16:34:09 UTC 2023 : Endpoint response headers: {date=Sun, 30 Jul 2023 16:34:08 GMT, server=uvicorn, content-length=22, content-type=application/json}
Sun Jul 30 16:34:09 UTC 2023 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"detail":"Not Found"}
Sun Jul 30 16:34:09 UTC 2023 : Method response body after transformations: {"detail":"Not Found"}
```

The 404 is coming from my server. You can see that from the server type "uvicorn". I can also see the container logs.

It appears that the Gateway is routing requests to `/`. I can see the following logs
`July 30, 2023 at 12:54 (UTC-4:00)  INFO: 192.168.62.160:39839 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found`

In order to ensure I was really getting all the way to my server, I added another handler on my app at `/`. I can see that the requests are being handled properly.  So ultimately it looks like the API GW is dropping the path components and just sending everything to `/`

I think my issue is related to Proxy Resource usage. I'm not sure I'm setting my resources/methods up correctly

Seems related to - [AWS API Gateway HTTP Proxy mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806319/aws-api-gateway-http-proxy-) but that is unanswered

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue while accessing my .NET APIs using Proxy Integration from a child route in API Gateway.

I fixed the issue by letting my .NET API know that the incoming request will have a prefix in the URL. So, that it would parse the API route correctly by ignoring the prefix.

```cs
app.UsePathBase("/api-gw-resource-prefix");
```

So, I guess you should do similar in your Python API as well.

> I don't have experience in Python, but if you are using **FastAPI**, then you can use something similar as shown in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71839736/1273882).